# My app in AdMob console isn't linked to Google Play anymore?

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-console

I had my app re-enabled after 30 days suspension. But the ads didn't get served even after months. Then I noticed that my app in ***AdMob console*** had no Icon to it, only the app name. I checked the ***'App settings'*** and there it says ***'Not linked to Google Play'***. So, I click edit and searched for my app, but it says ***'added'*** when I find my app.

So, I thought it might be because of this that I am no longer receiving ads? And what could be the problem of ***'Not linked to Google Play'***.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be related to app suspension. You have to link your Google Play and Google Ads accounts. Refer below link for more details.

https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6068602?hl=en

Comment: I think that may not be issue. I don't remember linking or doing anything on Google Ads accounts before I setup my AdMob though it worked fine.The AdMob console linking is about linking app to AdMob, which simply isn't working. And I am wondering now, what actually is Google Ads account?

Answer (score 0):

1st of all check [Policy Center](https://apps.admob.com/v2/policycenter) in AdMob, and make sure your app does not have any pending issues.

Also adding [app-ads.txt](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9363762?hl=en) file and linking it properly to your app could help.

If you don't have any problem, just wait. it may take up to 1 month for the icon to appear again, this related to the way AdMob fetches data from Google Play store.

Note: also if your app is not available on all countries (Especially US) the icon could never appear again.